# Call a result as a column name

Tags: r

I have a clustering result coded has `best.seed` To be clear if the result of best.seed is uc.4 and I wrote :

```
for(i in 1:16) {
      assign(paste0("Factor", i), row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.4 == i)))
    }
```

My loop is working.
But, if I try to call the `best.seed` or `best.seed[1]` result instead that is not working. Result are empty

```
for(i in 1:16) {
      assign(paste0("Factor", i), row.names(subset(res.uc.df, best.seed == i)))
    }
```

Comment: You'd get more answers if you made your problem reproducible

Comment: It would really help to see an example of your data and what you want as output

Comment: please check my new edit. If I get no answer I will remove the thread and post a new one with the data

Comment: Oh thanks ! that was easy, I think I have some problem to explain my problem. Post it as an answer If you want I will validate it.

Comment: But it was clear with your last edit. Thanks for the validation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i in 1:16) {
      assign(paste0("Factor", i), row.names(subset(res.uc.df, get(best.seed) == i)))
    }
```

should work.

Comment: You can understand why it is solution by master [Non-standard evaluations in R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#subset).